# How can I integrated LibGDX in Android application (Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, libgdx

When I run the Android Application there is some initialize and after that THERE IS connection to server when the connection end, I see on the screen Three Fragment Tabs.

Tab1 - Welcome to app.

Tab2 - Make some calculation.

tab3 - Game.

I want only when user type on "tab3 - game" to start/run active the LibGDX.

How can I do it?

Many Thanks For any help.

My Code MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.stam;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        final ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        addTabs(actionBar);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
                Log.d("VIVZ","onPageScrolled "+i+" "+v+" "+i2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
                Log.d("VIVZ","onPageSelected "+i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                if(i==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                Log.d("VIVZ","onPageScrollStateChanged scroll state idle "+i);
                if(i==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                    Log.d("VIVZ","onPageScrollStateChanged scroll state dragging "+i);
                if(i==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
                    Log.d("VIVZ","onPageScrollStateChanged scroll state settling "+i);
            }
        });

        }
    private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
    {
        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
//        Log.d("VIVZ","onTabSelected "+tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//        Log.d("VIVZ","onTabUnselected "+tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//        Log.d("VIVZ","onTabReselected "+tab.getText());
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(i==0)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentA();
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentB();
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentGame();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

My code FragmentGame.java:

```
package com.example.stam;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentGame extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c,container,false);
    }
}
```